# Google Script and Google Sheets modify code to delete row

Tags: google-sheets-api

I need help with a script in Google Sheets.

```
if(s.getName() == "Assigned" && r.getColumn() == 11 && r.getValue() == "No Bid")
{
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn() +1;
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("No Bid");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, numColumns);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
}
```

I just want to delete the row after it copies itself to the new sheet.
I am very new to this, I'm sure it's a single line, but not sure what it is.
Thank You for your help.

Comment: Figure it out....go me

Comment: Added at the end

s.deleteRow(row);